# Get data from JSON to List and use this to RecyclerView using GSON

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, gson

I have got a problem. I must get data from JSON to List<> and use this to RecyclerViewAdapter.

This is my JSON:

```
{
"lajt": [{
    "Nazwa": "Rower",
    "Cena": "300"
}, {
    "Nazwa": "Rower mtb",
    "Cena": "350"
}, {
    "Nazwa": "Pilka",
    "Cena": "50.7"
}]e
}
```

I used class generated on this site: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

This site generated 2 class. In the first class, I have got only List<> with objects from Lajt.class.

In Lajt.class, I have 2 strings ( first is "*Nazwa*", second is "*Cena*" ).

I must use this lists in RecyclerViewAdapter.

Can I make 2 lists( first list have got names(*Nazwa*), second have prices(*Cena*)?

Who has got a better idea?

Please help me. I am a beginner on working with GSON.

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you can give a quick outline of the `RecyclerViewAdapter` and then explain why the two-field Lajt class is not immediately compatible. What exactly does `RecyclerViewAdapter` need that Lajt does not have? Even though this information is probably available online (elsewhere), you should always include the basic ideas in the post itself so that anyone can understand the question without having to go searching.

Comment: I would not suggest that you make two lists. I assume they would need to be synchronized. So why not use what the website provided.

Comment: I mean, how to add each value with the key "Nazwa" was added to the first List <> and the value with the key "Cena" to the second List

Comment: Next, I add first List to first TextView in bar, and add second List to second TextView in this same bar.